# Item value in JSTL foreach loop not working in Portlet

Tags: jsp, portlet, el

Given the following Portlet Code:

```
ArrayList nameList = new ArrayList();
nameList.add("Willi Willisch");
nameList.add("Seppi Seppisch");

renderRequest.setAttribute("names", nameList);
```

And the following JSP Code:

```
<c:forEach var="aName" items="${names}">
    <tr>
       <td>${aName} </td>
    </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

Prints out:

```
${aName}
${aName}
```

I don't have any clue why a $(aName) isn't evaluated. The forEach loops works, because ${aName} is printed out twice ....

Comment: Out of interest, what does `<c:out value="${aName}"/>` do?

Comment: `<c:out value="${aName}"/>` works!! But shouldn't `${aName}` work aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `<c:out value="${aName}"/>` works!! But shouldn't `${aName}` work aswell?

Thus, "EL in template text" doesn't work? That can have one or more of the following causes:

1. Application server in question doesn't support JSP 2.0.
2. The `web.xml` is not declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.
3. The `@page` is configured with `isELIgnored=true`.
4. The `web.xml` is configured with `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>` in `<jsp-config>`.

To fix one or other, obviously do:

1. Upgrade server or use JSTL `c:out` instead and live with it.
2. Preferably declare `web.xml` to latest Servlet API version supported by appserver.
3. Remove the `isELIgnored=true` attribute.
4. Remove the `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>` entry.