# JSTL taglib issue

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a simple maven web project. I simply can't figure out a way to have the JSTL tags work.
For testing purposes, I've created a dummy project having no dependency except for:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in my JSP page, I have the following test code -

```
<c:set var="hello" value="see this?"/>
<c:out value="${hello}"></c:out>
<h2>${hello}</h2>
<br/>
<%=request.getAttribute("hello") %>
```

I have also included the jstl declaration on the top -
`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

However, this does not seem to work. Surprisingly, the `${hello}` doesn't show anything meaningful, but the `request.getAttribute...` does. This means that the `c:set` is actually working, and both the `c:out` and simple expression do NOT work. Am I missing out something here?

Any help is appreciated - been trying to get my head around this for 3 days now!

Comment: In case it is still not working with the answer provided by JB Nizet, have a look at the answer of this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536333/item-value-in-jstl-foreach-loop-not-working-in-portlet

Comment: Or just hover the `[jstl]` tag below the question and click *info* link on the popbox :)

Comment: i believe BalusC's comment actually qualifies as the 'source' of the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in checking out the [info document on JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) provided within StackOverflow. It mentions almost everything there is to know about why your JSTL installation may not be working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The JSTL jar only contains the standard classes and interfaces of the spec, but no implementation for the tags.

Add this dependency to your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW, always look at the generated HTML code to see what's going on. And the `c:set` tag sets a **page** scope attribute, not a **request** scope attribute, so the fact that `request.getAttribute("hello")` outputs something doesn't have anything to do with the `c:set` tag placed before.

Comment: i thought using the jstl ver `1.2` obviated the need to use the `standard` jar. and yes, i had actually set the variable to request scope, missed out while copying: `<c:set var="hello" value="see this?" scope="request"/>`